# What type of the word is "be + past participle"

Tags: modal-verbs, subordinate-clauses, past-participles, passive-voice

In sentence:

> A growing set of on-line applications are generating data that can **be viewed** as...

What are the words *be viewed*? For me they sound like passive voice (*be viewed by someone*), but that cannot be as this sentence is already active. So in which situations I can use *be + p.p.*?

Comment: "can"  can be followed by an infinitive active (I can do it) or an infinitive passive (It can be done).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Can be viewed* is indeed passive. Its use here is correct, because this verbgroup heads a distinct clause: a subordinate relative clause which modifies *data*. This construction unites two distinct propositions:

1. A growing set of on-line applications are generating data.
2. These data can be viewed as ...

Comment: I see. So in this situation there is an exception in forming passive voice (because there is no conjugation of the verb to be). Can you please provide me some link from which I can learn how to distinguish such situations? Or what I need to search to find this? Thanks

Comment: @chao I don't understand what you mean either by an 'exception' here or by 'no conjugation of the verb to be'. Could you explain in more detail what unusual circumstance you see here?

Comment: Aha, OK. I've learned that passive voice is always formed by conjugating to be - e.g. Data are stolen. So, I don't understand why in this situation is `be`. Of course that be viewed sounds normal to me, but I don't have grammar background for that, so I would like to know if this is some special form of passive or what?

Comment: @chao Ah ... in this case the verb group is headed by the modal verb *can*. A *MODAL* always followed by an infinitive (in this case, *be*), just as auxiliary *HAVE* is always followed by a past participle and auxiliary *BE* is followed by a past participle (for the passive) or a present participle (for the progressive). (The all-caps verbforms here represent "whatever form of this verb is used in the particular situation".)